# Does &quot prints " in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was going through the following piece of code:

```
try:
            with open('python.json', 'a') as f:
                f.write(data)
                return True
except BaseException as e:
            print(&quot;Error on_data: %s&quot; % str(e))
```

I am not quite able to explain what does the `print` statement do here?

Comment: It prints error, just for debugging or something.

Comment: I get a `SyntaxError` as I would expect.  How are you running this?  It looks like an artifact of a web REPL.

Answer (score 3):

It does not do anything, it's a syntax error.

The example you pasted probably went through some oh-my-god-I-need-to-escape-all-special-characters-zomg-css-attacks handling that mercilessly replaced the `"`.